# Navigation Drawer closing is not smooth for a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a `Navigation Drawer` for my app that works correctly for the most part.

My `Home` tab does a couple of API requests in order to display some information, these requests and the workload they require (even if it is rather minimal) block the closing of the Drawer midway, making it not smooth.

My first "solution" was [to load the fragment only after the Drawer closes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486129/5448913), like such:

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);

            displaySelectedScreen(itemSelected.getItemId());
        }
    };
```

But this creates a 0.5s wait before the Fragments view gets displayed, and that is not very apealing from a user standpoint.

Here is part of my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

This is how I display my `Fragment`s so far:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {      
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here is what happens in `displaySelectedScreen`:

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment;
    fragment = checkFragment(itemId); // Instantiates the right Fragment

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Close our Drawer since we have selected a valid item.
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

What could you recommend for my `Navigation Drawer` to close smoothly?

**EDIT**:

As requested, here is my code for my `AsyncTask` that does the API request and returns a `JSONObject`:

```
/**
 * Requests information from the API via APIRequests
 * Extends AsyncTask in order to do network-related actions in background.
 */
private class SearchInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONObject information;

        APIRequests apiRequests = new APIRequests();
        information = apiRequests.getGameInfo();

        requestDone = true;

        return information;
    }
}
```

`APIRequest`'s method does a simple `HTTP GET` via `HttpURLConnection` and returns a `JSONObject` with the data retrieved.

Comment: what happens in displaySelectedScreen() ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you commit Fragment in displaySelectedScreen(), before the drawer closes

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {      
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId()); // Commit is there
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); // And drawer closing simultaneously
    return true;
}
```

What would I do is

```
// Create a field that marks that something needs to be displayed
// after drawer closes. When null means no action (drawer closed
// by the user, not by selecting an item)
Integer itemIdWhenClosed;

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {      
    itemIdWhenClosed = item.getItemId(); // Mark action when closed
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); // Close it
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    // If id to show is marked, perform action
    if (itemIdWhenClosed != null) {
        displaySelectedScreen(itemIdWhenClosed);
        // Reset value
        itemIdWhenClosed = null;
    }
}

// Now here just commit, don't close the drawer since this is already
// fired when it's closed
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
    final Fragment fragment = checkFragment(itemId);
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: As I have said, my first "solution" was to load the Fragment after the Drawer closes, but the little delay it has ruins the fluidity of the interface. Thank you for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without making API requests, and see if the problem is on the display of the fragment?

Comment: Absolutely, it is very smooth without the request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use another thread to do the API requests in. You can use `AsyncTask`, `Loaders`, `Services`, `IntentServices`, etc depending on what the specific API request is. That way the `Fragment` can be displayed immediately and the data can be added to it when it's loaded

Comment: I already do my API Requests in an AsyncTask background method.

Comment: And if you don't execute the AsyncTask everything runs smoothly? If so could you show the code of AsyncTask as well?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have used is as follows:

Since the data I display won't change often (not on a daily basis at least), I now do my API requests only once per session (process) of my app.

```
 if (!requestDone) { // Where requestDone == true when I have done an API request
      getGameInfo();
 }
```

And instantiate the Fragment only when it has not been instantiated (in order to keep `requestDone`'s value).

The animation is now fluid at all times (since I have a splash screen that ends when the API requests are done).

It seems obvious to me now that the number of time data is requested must be equivalent to its probability of being updated.